# Binding mode for arrow keys in i3wm

Tags: vi, i3

I want to create a binding mode in i3wm which remaps `j` and `k` as `ArrowDown` and `ArrowUp`. Somewhat like this.

```
mode "readmode" {
bindsym k Down
bindsym j Up
bindsym Space mode "default"
}

bindsym $super+v mode "readmode"
```

Is it possible to do so?

Also, the mappings should return to normal (default) when the mode is exited.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you out:

```
mode "moveit" {
    bindsym k move up 20 px
    bindsym h move left 20 px
    bindsym j move down 20 px
    bindsym l move right 20 px

    bindsym Up move up 5 px
    bindsym Left move left 5 px
    bindsym Down move down 5 px
    bindsym Right move right 5 px

    # back to normal: Enter or Escape
    bindsym Return mode "default"
    bindsym Escape mode "default"
    bindsym $mod+m mode "default"
}
```

Comment: Please add code as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow copy-&-paste; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.